# Not able to ignore static files from getting pushed to git in Django project

Tags: django, git

I had pushed a new Django project BTRE to my git repository. But I can't ignore the static files from pushed to the repository even though I have mentioned the directories in `.gitignore` file.

```
-BTRE_Project
|-btre
   |-static
```

This is my `.gitignore` file:

```
# If your build process includes running collectstatic, then you probably don't need or want to include staticfiles/
# in your Git repository. Update and uncomment the following line accordingly.

btre/static/
```

I have tried deleting the repository and pushing again after updating the `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to ignore your static folder and all the files inside it, put this in your `.gitignore` file.

```
static/
```

This will ignore the static directory and files inside that.

Comment: for more information check this official DOC. https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Answer (score 0):

You can add ignore by adding the folder path in .gitignore file also use git lfs if you want to commit static files.